# Remove CellMargins option from many cells

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options

I have a very old notebook in which many cells had the `CellMargins` option set manually. What's the easiest way to remove all those manual option settings?

Comment: @R.M I think it only looks for incompatibilities, and I'm guessing `CellMargins` has been around for a long time.

Comment: @R.M.: no, the compatibility check does $not$ ask about `CellMargins`. After all, that's a legitimate cell option still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following line to the end of the notebook you want to update:

```
NotebookPut[NotebookGet[] /. Verbatim[Rule][CellMargins, e__] -> Sequence[]];
```

And evaluate it. You should get a new notebook for which all `CellMargins` have been deleted.

---

Looks like you can use the UI pretty easily to do this. First, highlight all the cells (if you want all the cells to have the same margins, just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Then, go to Format -> Options Inspector (also can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). In the search box, you can type in `CellMargins`:

[image]

Here, I've set the marings to be `{{66,10},{5,25}}`. It looks like the default is `{{66,10},{5,10}}` and the settings are `{{left,right},{top,bottom}}`

Comment: I did $not$ ask how to change the `CellMargin` option (I certainly know how to do that using the Options Inspector). I want to $remove$ the option entirely from all cells (so that the margins will be whatever the stylesheet sets by default).

Comment: @murray All cells have the CellMargins attribute, I don't think you can "remove" it. Do you mean you would like to restore it separately for each cell type that it is in? I.e., an input cell has the default style for the default stylesheet? If so, that certainly wasn't clear from your question, and questions for which users don't know about the options inspector have come up, so I don't know how I could've known all that.

Comment: No, all cells do $not$ have a `CellMargins` attribute as part of their expression--although of course they are in effect given cell margin settings by the cell style. E.g., in a new nb create any Input cell then look at its expression; you will $not$ see any `CellMargins` option there!

Comment: @murray not all cells have an *explicit* `CellMargins`, but I believe the front end keeps track of it as a default. But I do see what you mean: see my edit.

Comment: @murray, the little cross at the left of the options in the options inspector, when removed, removes the explicit option settings, and shows whatever value is inherited. Now you certainly know how to remove the options using the options inspector too

Comment: The `NotebookPut[NotebookGet[]...]` expression did it; thanks!

So did the Options Inspector method. I'm quite familiar with using the Options Inspector, but I was making the mistake of choosing `Notebook` in the first field (when no little `x` would appear) instead of selecting all notebook cells and then choosing `Selection` (which did reveal the `x` on the `CellMargins` option).

Comment: @murray glad it worked!